# PHP routing is not working properly with apache .htaccess configuration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've created a basic routing system by reading a [freecodecamp blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-routing-system-in-php/). But it is not working properly as it should be.

#### Project directory:

```bash
.
├── .htaccess
├── index.php
└── views
    ├── 404.php
    ├── dep.php
    ├── home.php
    └── users.php
```

#### .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

#### index.php

```php
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$dir = __DIR__ . '/views/';

switch ($request) {
  case '': 
  case '/': 
    require $dir . 'home.php';
    break;
  case '/views/users': 
    require $dir . 'users.php';
    break;
  case '/views/department':
    require $dir . 'dep.php';
    break;
  default: 
    http_response_code(404);
    require $dir . '404.php';
    break;
}
```

While accessing `localhost/` it works fine and opens the page `home.php` and on trying to accessing urls like: `localhost/anything` or `localhost/a/b...` it shows the `404.php`. But if I want to open the `localhost/views` or `localhost/views/department` or `localhost/views/users` it is showing the default php `Not Found` error page.

---

#### *Update*

On changing the case in the switch statement from `/views/users` to `anything/users` it works perfectly. It is accessible to url `localhost/anyting/users`. 
***Summary*** 
If I use the directory name in the switch case it doesn't work and if I change it to anything else it is working.

---

I'm using php integrated server by running command `php -S localhost:80` on PHP 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using PHP's built-in web server which does not supports `.htaccess` file. So, the above configuration provided in the `.htaccess` is not running, but PHP built-in web server uses its own routing techniques.

### [PHP Built-in webserver Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

> URI requests are served from the current working directory where PHP was started, unless the -t option is used to specify an explicit document root. If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned. If neither file exists, the lookup for index.php and index.html will be continued in the parent directory and so on until one is found or the document root has been reached. If an index.php or index.html is found, it is returned and $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is set to the trailing part of the URI. Otherwise a 404 response code is returned.

#### As per the above quote:

- If you try to access `localhost/anything/a/b` without a file extension in it, then PHP web server process it as you are not specifying a file and it will checks for the `index.php` or `index.html` file from innermost directory to the host until it finds a `index.php` or `index.html` file, and it serves it. But in this recursion process, if there is a directory availbale with the same name and there isn't any `index.php` or `index.html` file present then server will show the `PHP - 404 error page`.

### Example:

```
.
├── .htaccess
├── index.php
├── server
│   └── contact.php
└── views
    ├── 404.php
    ├── dep.php
    ├── home.php
    ├── index.php
    └── users.php
```

- On trying to access `localhost/views/users` regardless of anything in the root `./index.php` it will process `./views/index.php`.
- On trying to access the `localhost/server/contact` regardless of anything in the root `./index.php` it will show the `PHP - 404 error page`.
- On trying to access `localhost/anything/a/b/c` it will check recursively for the right directory, and if it isn't matches any then process the `./index.php`.
- So, you've to create a router in the every directory with the name of `index.php`.
- Or you can use names of the routes which are not used in the original directory names. Like `view/users` for `views/users` in the `./index.php` file, then it will show you the page correctly.