# Basic Configuring of PHPDebug/Xdebug and VSCode - Setting Root Folder

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Probably a newbie question but I'm having a hard time understanding/configuring PHPDebug/Xdebug in VSCode & Windows. Best way I can explain is to use an example below.

Say my project structure is like below, with a root folder, several App folders, and a SharedFolder containing files used by all the Apps.

```text
C:\WebAppRoot
C:\WebAppRoot\App
C:\WebAppRoot\App2
C:\WebAppRoot\SharedFiles\src
C:\WebAppRoot\SharedFiles\img
```

Say I load a project located at `C:\WebAppRoot\App`. I have several calls to files located in the `SharedFiles` directory and are referenced like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SharedFiles/src/script.js>
```

But when I launch the "Launch Built-in web server" option these files cannot be located since the localhost is pointing to `C:\WebAppRoot\App` as the root.

I don't know how to configure the launch.json to start at the root directory `C:\WebAppRoot`. I've tried using `pathMappings` and a bunch of other configurations but it doesn't work and doesn't really make sense to me.

Here's my current config. Any help would be much appreciated!

```json
{
    "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
        "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
        "-S",
        "localhost:0"
    ],
    "log": true,
    "program": "",
     "pathMappings": {
         "c:/WebAppRoot":"${workspaceRoot}",
    },
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "port": 9003,
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
        "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
        "action": "openExternally"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your code compiled from PHP to HTML and then rendered in the DOM. Then the client machine makes a request to the server for a file which is a level up in the directory, and for the security reason you can't access that file. 
This way you can access PHP files because that will be processes by the server beforehand, and than compiled code will be served to the user.

### Edited

I was unable to find any configuration, but your server (in mysite.example.com) is basically running a single server in the root directory, and assigned diffrent URL to your websites. like...

- `localhost/siteone` -> `siteone.example.com`
- `localhost/sitetwo` -> `sitetwo.example.com`

So, this way you are able to access your files in the root directory. And if you want to do this in you own computer, then you've to install `apache server` or `xampp` because `php in-built development server` havn't any option to configure. [see this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76212682/php-routing-is-not-working-properly-with-apache-htaccess-configuration)

### See this routing tutorial

[How to Build a Routing System for a PHP App from Scratch](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-routing-system-in-php/)

Comment: That makes sense in theory, but how do I configure it to work like it does on the production server? For example www.mysite.com/app/index.php loads scripts & images located in the sharedfiles directory. How do I make the localhost follow the same behavior?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get better clarification. I ended up just using a default Launch Chrome configuration in conjunction with xampp and this seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Please! check mark the answer for right answer. If it helped you.